# Using a Sender as global State in a Tauri Plugin

Tags: rust, atomic, tauri

## Issue

I'm attempting to write a relatively large-scale Tauri Application and divide it into plugins as recommended by the Tauri docs.

The only issue being these plugins need to be able to call upon each other.

Since the traditional way in rust to send messages across a program is the `std::sync::mpsc::channel`, I thought to try using that and put a sender of the plugins specific set of commands in the Tauri global state via `AppHandle<R: Runtime>::manage` function during the initialisation of each plugin.

The problem with this solution is the `manage` function require the `state` to be `Send + Sync` and the `Sender` is `Send + !Sync`.

## Code Sample

### Initlialise Function

Attempts to put the sender in global state

```rust
fn initialize(
    &mut self,
    handle: &tauri::AppHandle<R>,
    config: serde_json::Value,
) -> PluginResult<()> {
    let cfg = Config::from_serde_value(config)?;

    handle.manage(DiscordRichPresence::new_mutex(&cfg.client_id));
    handle.manage(self.sender.clone());

    Ok(())
}
```

Any ideas as to any wrapper types of a form of "Clone on Read" type that may be able to help?

Happy to provide more code sample if needed to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

the answer is to use `tokio::sync::mspc::channel` instead of `std::sync::mpsc::channel` since the `tokio` one is `Send + Sync` as opposed to the `std` `Sender` which is `Send + !Sync`.

just add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.23.0", features = ["sync"] }
```

However, if you require it to be Synchronous, `std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel` *should* also work, though, in the case of Tauri, async is recommended since Tauri is itself built on top of Tokio. and making commands asynchronous is easy.